# Loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help with my loop.
I try to get data from Google Finance API.
Google doesn't provide multi-tiker API so 1 request per 1 ticker.
For 1 ticker, it's work well, but I need more than one.
I try to do it in a loop but I get

> undefined[object Object][object Object]

```
  .controller('currency', function ($scope, $http){
  var tickers =["EURUSD","AUDUSD]; 
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   $http.get('https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=CURRENCY%3a'+tickers[i]).then(function successCallback(response) {
              $scope.currencydata = $scope.currencydata + JSON.parse(response.data.substr(3));


        })}
    })
```

Comment: `$http.get` is asynchronous

Comment: use $q.all, for all promises

Comment: I think there is a missing closing quotation mark in
`var tickers =["EURUSD","AUDUSD"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON.parse method outputs an object. You cannot do a plus operation on two objects.

Change the following:

```
$scope.currencydata = $scope.currencydata + JSON.parse(response.data.substr(3));
```

To this:

```
$scope.currencydata.push(JSON.parse(response.data.substr(3)));
```

Make sure to initialize the $scope.currencydata variable before the loop.

```
$scope.currencydata = [];
```

Otherwise the .push method will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

Use $q.all in angular

Do some thing like

```
var functionsToFire = []
["EURUSD","AUDUSD].forEach(function(currncy){
   var hello = create http request function
   functionsToFire.push(hello)
})

$q.all(functionsToFire).then(function (result) {
 console.log(result)
});
```

AND ULTIMATELY IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS

```
$q.all([request1function, request2function, request3function, request4function]).then(function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        theResults.push(result[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `"`. Try this:

```
 .controller('currency', function ($scope, $http){
      var tickers =["EURUSD","AUDUSD"]; 
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       $http.get('https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=CURRENCY%3a'+tickers[i]).then(function successCallback(response) {
                  $scope.currencydata = $scope.currencydata + JSON.parse(response.data.substr(3));


            })}
        })
```

Comment: yea loss " when copy. Thx